# Submit AJAX Forms with JQuery not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

After I filled out the form and it validated the form that was filled by displaying success message - that works (also validated the blanks by displaying the error message - works OK too), but it doesnt send any data to my email. It does not even go through `contact_mail.php` to alert the message.

What did I do wrong?

**jQuery/AJAX** (UPDATED)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#contactMe").on("click", function() {
    if ($(".box").is(":hidden")) {
      $(".box").slideDown("fast");
    } else {
      $(".box").slideUp("fast");
    }
  });
  $(".btn-close").on("click", function() {
    $(".box").slideUp("fast");
  });
});

function sendContact() {
  var valid;
  valid = validateContact();
    if (valid) {
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: "contact_mail.php",
        data: 'frm-fname=' + $("#frm-fname").val() + '&frm-email=' +
        $("#frm-email").val() + '&frm-company=' +
        $("#frm-company").val() + '&frm-comment=' + $("#frm-comment").val(),
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
          $("#mail-status").html(data);
          setTimeout(ajaxCallback, 2000);
        },
      error: function() {}
    });
  }
}

function ajaxCallback() {
  var btnHTML = '<button type="submit" name="frm-submit" class="btn-submit" onclick="sendContact()">SEND</button>';
  $("#mail-status").html(btnHTML);
  $(".box").slideUp("slow");
}

function validateContact() {
  var valid = true;
    if (
      $("#frm-fname").val().match(/^\s*$/) ||
      $("#frm-email").val().match(/^\s*$/) ||
      !$("#frm-email").val().match(/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/) ||
      $("#frm-company").val().match(/^\s*$/) ||
      $("#frm-comment").val().match(/^\s*$/)
    ) {
    valid = false;
  }

  if (valid) {
    $(".frm-suc-msg").show();
    $(".frm-error-msg").hide();
  } else {
    $(".frm-error-msg").show();
    $(".frm-suc-msg").hide();
  }

  return valid;
}

if (window.history.replaceState) {
  window.history.replaceState(null, null, window.location.href);
}
</script>
```

(ERROR PER CONSOLE) - contact_mail.php **FIXED!!**

```
jquery.min.js:2          
POST ../contact_mail.php 500 (Internal Server 
Error)
send @ jquery.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
sendContact @ indexdev.php:610
onclick @ indexdev.php:152
```

**contact_mail.php** (FIXED!! WHAT A BONEHEAD! I HAD A FAKE EMAIL ADDRESS!)

```
$toEmail = "myemail@hotmail.com";
$mailHeaders = "From: " . $_POST["frm-fname"] . "<" . $_POST["frm-email"] . ">\r\n";
  if (mail($toEmail, $_POST["frm-company"], $_POST["frm-comment"], $mailHeaders)) {
  //print "<p class='success'>Contact Mail Sent.</p>";
  echo '<script>alert("SUCCESS")</script>'; <--- I showed this
 } else {
 //print "<p class='error'>Problem in Sending Mail.</p>";
 echo '<script>alert("FAILED")</script>';
}
```

**FORM in HTML** (UPDATED)

```
<div class="frm-group">
  <input name="frm-fname" type="text" id="frm-fname">
  <span class="frm-highlight"></span>
  <span class="frm-bar"></span>
  <label>Full Name:</label>
</div>
<div class="frm-group">
  <input name="frm-email" type="email" id="frm-email">
  <span class="frm-highlight"></span>
  <span class="frm-bar"></span>
  <label>Email:</label>
</div>
<div class="frm-group">
  <input name="frm-company" type="text" id="frm-company">
  <span class="frm-highlight"></span>
  <span class="frm-bar"></span>
  <label>Company Name:</label>
</div>
<div class="frm-group">
  <textarea name="frm-comment" rows="3" id="frm-comment"></textarea>
  <span class="frm-highlight"></span>
  <span class="frm-bar"></span>
  <label>Message:</label>
</div>
<div id="mail-status">
  <button type="button" name="frm-submit" class="btn-submit" onclick="sendContact()">SEND</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you looked in browser console to confirm that nothing being sent in network tab? also, you have `error: function() {}` which obviously useless if you need to troubleshoot. Replace it with `error: function(er) {console.log(er)}`

Comment: Variable `content` is not defined, so the provided code fails at `$(content).val()`

Comment: in php there is no alert function, add echo and php header (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php - 200 - ok, 400 bad, and next use error: function(er) {console.log(er) :)

Comment: @ArkadiuszG, headers have nothing to do here 

Comment: @vanowm without headers you will always be "success" and it is not true.

Comment: @ArkadiuszG. I think you are mistaken headers for [`mail()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) and HTTP, they are not the same.

Comment: `type="submit"` change to `type="button"` , html form cant separate the request from js

Comment: @vanown never mind, thought you were the author of the question, sorry :)

Comment: I updated the `conact_mail.php` file and it went through by displaying `SUCCESS!`, but still havent receive any data from the form by email.